# How can I handle MySQL queries in JavaScript with those asynchronous functions?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, asynchronous

could someone help me with my problem? I'm new to JavaScript (Node.js) and try to perform MySQL queries but this outputs nothing. I don't know how to handle this.

```
async function processArguments() {
    var result_customer = [];
    for(let i = 2; i < process.argv.length; ++i) {
        let sql = "SELECT Mandantennummer, Firmenname, VornameAnsp, NachnameAnsp, Telefonnummer, Strasse, PLZ"
                  "FROM kunde, item"
                  "WHERE kunde.K_ID=item.K_ID AND I_ID="+ process.argv[i];

        await link.query(sql, function(err_customer, customer, fields_customer) {
            if(err_customer) throw err_customer;
            result_customer.push(customer);
        });
    }

    for(let i = 0; i < result_customer.length; ++i) {
        console.log(result_customer[i].Firmenname);
    }

    link.end();
}

link.connect(function(err) {
    if(err) throw err;

    processArguments();
});
```

This outputs nothing

Thanks for help

Comment: Try to use this code:`link.connect(async function(err) {
    if(err) throw err;

   await processArguments();
});`

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: check this filter in your query WHERE kunde.K_ID=item.K_ID

Comment: I guess you have hard coded it with a string instead of passing a value.Use object literals if you actually want to do this

Comment: I think there is something wrong with your sql query itself. Try to run it wither from mysql workbench or from terminal

Comment: What's the library? Is it `mysql`? Use promise-based libraries together with promises,

Comment: The query works

Comment: I installed this library with npm and it is called mysql

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `callback` functions as `Promise` which will not work. You need to promisify the query.

```
async function processArguments() {
    var result_customer = [];
    for (let i = 2; i < process.argv.length; ++i) {
        let sql = "SELECT Mandantennummer, Firmenname, VornameAnsp, NachnameAnsp, Telefonnummer, Strasse, PLZ"
        "FROM kunde, item"
        "WHERE kunde.K_ID=item.K_ID AND I_ID=" + process.argv[i];

        const customer = await new Promise((resolve, rej) => {
            link.query(sql, function (err_customer, customer, fields_customer) {
                if (err_customer) rej(err_customer);
                resolve(customer);
            });
        });
        result_customer.push(customer);
    }
    link.end();
}

link.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;

    await processArguments();
});
```

If you want to `await`, it needs to be a `Promise` or an `async` function.

Edit: You can concat the process.argv[i] and use it along with `IN` in that query.

```
let sql = `SELECT Mandantennummer, Firmenname, VornameAnsp, NachnameAnsp, Telefonnummer, Strasse, PLZ 
FROM kunde, item 
WHERE kunde.K_ID=item.K_ID AND I_ID IN (${process.argv.slice(2).join(',')})`;
```

Comment: Yes, it works. I forgot async before function at connect